# I want to add sub-index in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my datatable index below. (a lot of data)

| index1 | contents |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | water |
| 1 | chocolate milk |
| 1 | strawberry milk |
| 2 | milk coffee |
| 2 | butter coffee |
| 2 | custom coffee |
| 3 | etc |
| ... | ... |

and I want to make this below

| index1 | index2 | contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | water |
| 1 | 1 | chocolate milk |
| 1 | 2 | strawberry milk |
| 2 | 1 | milk coffee |
| 2 | 2 | butter coffee |
| 2 | 3 | custom coffee |
| 3 | 1 | etc |
| ... | ... | ... |

I know how to manually create and paste indexes,
but I can't do that because the data I have is longer than 1000 lines of data.

Comment: What's the logic of your index 2?

Comment: It's counting index1 numbers in order.

Comment: example : 0 is one thing so 1. 1 is two things, so I wrote 1, 2 in order.

Comment: Use `groupby.ngroup.add(1)`

Comment: Is that an index or a column? It looks like a simple groupby cumcount if it's a column _e.g._ `df['index2'] = df.groupby('index1').cumcount() + 1`